# Doctrine change UTF8 encoding to html entities when saving data in database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I don't know where this problem is coming from although I did not touch doctrin's configuration but when I send to database a word with special characters like this (`Réparation`) doctrine save it this way (`R&eacute;paration`) !!
I'm using `latin1_swedish_ci` as `Interclassement` in both database and table.
and this is doctrin's configuration in `config.yml` file:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

What am I doing wrong ?
**UPDATE**:
I just found that only one column save data this way if I use another column date are saved correctly !!
How do you explain this ?

Comment: That's not work of doctrine or mysql. How did you store the entity? What's the encoding of your page?

Comment: @Federkun I'm using UTF8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where this problem is coming from:
It was from `tinymce` (the WYSIWYG editor) that converts the special characters to `html_entities`.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        options:
          1002:  "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
```

1002 is the value for the constant [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: Thx for your answer but sorry still the same problem :(